# I am getting Bad Request error when submiting form in flask

Tags: flask

So my form looks like this

```
<form action="{{ url_for('addnote') }}">
                Notatka: <input type="text" name="note" placeholder="Notatka">
                <br><br>
                <input onclick="document.getElementById('receiver').disabled ^= true;" type="checkbox" checked> Do wszystkich?
                <br><br>
                <input type="text" name="receiver" id="receiver" placeholder="Adresat" disabled="false" value="">
                <br><br>
                <input type="hidden" name="author" value="{{ current_user.username }}">
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Dodaj notatke">
            </form>
```

And my function in flask in this moment i have only this:

```
def addnote():
    note=request.form['note']
    author=request.form['author']
    receiver=request.form['receiver']
    return "whatever"
```

Later i would like to do something with this data but even with such a small amount of code i get BAD REQUEST error. I was looking for the solution but i cannot find any which helps in my case

Answer (score 0):

Your form doesn't have a `method="post"` attribute, so it will default to `get` resulting in URL key/value pairs (e.g. `/addnote?note=x&receiver=...`)

Also make sure your route is listening for POST:

```
@app.route('/addnote', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addnote():
    ...
```

Comment: Even when I am using post method I still get the same bad request, so this isn't it

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Flask WTForms. WTForms is an excellent Flask extension that handles this very well. It would look something like this using WTForms:

```
                           <div class="form-group">
                                {{ form.myField.label(class="form-control-label") }} {% if form.myField.errors %} {{ form.myField(class="form-control
                                form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    {% for errors in form.myField.errors %}
                                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                                {% else %} {{ form.myField(class="form-control form-control-lg") }} {% endif %}
                            </div>

                         <form action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/addnote" method="post">

                             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info" name="submit_button" value="Retrieve Data">

                         </form>
```

And server side would be something like:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo, ValidationError

class ToolForm(FlaskForm):
    myField = StringField('Enter Data', validators=[DataRequired()])

@app.route('/addnote', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addnote():
    form = ToolForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
         if request.form['submit_button'] == 'Retrieve Data':
             x = form.myField.data
```

Comment: For some reasons i am trying to avoid flask_wtf but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I didn't want to use flask_wtf but i find my way around this problem. Instead of using `author=request.form['author']` i am doing `author=request.form.get('author')`. I am not sure what was really causing the problem but this way this is working.